# IE - how to preserve white space in textarea, inputting with javascript string

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea, whitespace

FF and Chrome are behaving nicely, but IE (8) is not keeping the white space in my formatted code I'm putting into a TEXTAREA

```
<textarea id="vdt_table_textarea" style="white-space: pre"></textarea>
```

and

```
var vdt_demo_table_string = '&lt;table id=&quot;example&quot; class=&quot;display&quot;&gt;\n\
  &lt;thead&gt;\n\
    &lt;tr&gt;\n\
      &lt;th&gt;Rendering engine&lt;/th&gt;\n\
      &lt;th&gt;Browser&lt;/th&gt;\n\
      &lt;th&gt;Platform(s)&lt;/th&gt;\n\
      &lt;th&gt;Engine version&lt;/th&gt;\n\
      &lt;th&gt;CSS grade&lt;/th&gt;\n\
    &lt;/tr&gt;\n\
  &lt;/thead&gt;\n\
  etc....
';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vdt_table_textarea').html(vdt_demo_table_string.replace(' ', '&nbsp;'));
});
```

how can I make IE respect my authoritah?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your way doesn't work, but this does:

```
$('#vdt_table_textarea').html(vdt_demo_table_string.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;'));
```

Comment: excellent. thanks.  points to you.

I decided to go another route and just use tinymce for the source as well as allow visual editing of the table.

Comment: I believe you will find that the string.replace only replaces the first occurrance when doing string replacement.

Comment: @RogerWillcocks that's what the `g` at the end is for, stands for global I believe.

Answer (score 7):

CSS

```
textarea{
white-space:pre;
}
```

Or

```
textarea{
white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```